# What's the most suitable c++ replacement of calloc?

Tags: c++, c++17

The title says it.

I have tried:

```
new char[nSize];
```

but it can return uninitialized memory.
where as `calloc` ensures a zero-initialization.

I could call memset, etc. - but isn't there a more direct way ?

Comment: `new char[nSize]{};` will zero initialize.

Comment: `std::vector<char>` will be zero initialized.

Comment: And be sure you use `delete []` to deallocate. `std::vector` would be a better idea.

Comment: use `std::string` or `std::vector<char>`

Comment: You might want  to think about why you need zero initialisation. I can't remember ever needing it myself.

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux vector would normally be fine - unless i needed to own it - which i do here. So not a generel solution.

Comment: What do you mean by "own it"?

Comment: Note, that big allocation `calloc` is usually optimized by the OS (it has pre-allocated zero pages, and copy-on-write). So it could be much faster than any of the possible replacements.

Comment: If `calloc` is indeed what you need, what is stopping you from just using `std::calloc`?

Comment: @MichaelKenzel I need to modify heap allocations for finding heap erros (using VirtualAlloc and friends) - and this cannot easily be done with calloc - if possible at all.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> What's the most suitable c++ replacement of calloc?

For most purposes, `std::vector`. Or `std::string` if you intend to represent a character string. It will automatically delete whatever memory it allocates.

For data structures that contain many arrays that are not mutually contiguous, you might want to avoid the slightly-larger-than-pointer size of `std::vector`, and instead might opt for unique pointer:

```
auto ptr = std::make_unique<char[]>(nSize);
```

You can use value initialisation with a new expression as well. This is what `std::make_unique` does internally:

```
new char[nSize]();
```

But I would not recommend allocations without a RAII container.

---

As mentioned by [geza](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55620811/whats-the-most-suitable-c-replacement-of-calloc#comment97935431_55620811), `calloc` may be optimised (on some systems) such that it may elide setting the memory to zero when allocating a large block. If such optimisation applies to your case, and is measurably significant, then there may be an argument for using `std::calloc` in C++.